# jQuery not returning true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I do this:

```
function loginFunc(userNameOrEmail, passWord){
        var emailOrUserNameV = encodeURIComponent(userNameOrEmail);
        var passWordV = encodeURIComponent(passWord);
        $.getJSON("http://mysite.com/pullData/login.php?callback=?",
              {
                emailOrUserName: emailOrUserNameV,
                passWord: passWordV
              },
              function(recievedData) {
                if(recievedData[0] == 'true'){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }

        });

}
```

then I do this:

```
$('#loginBtnHtml').click(function(){
            var emailVar = $('#email_html').val();
            var pwdVar = $('#password_html').val();
            if(loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar)){
                alert('good');
            }
            else{
                alert('bad');
            }

        });
```

If I run the `loginFunc()` with an `alert(recievedData[0]);` It works fine how do I get it to return bool to the `$('#loginBtnHtml').click();` ?

When I do this to troubleshoot:

```
$('#loginBtnHtml').click(function(){
            var emailVar = $('#email_html').val();
            var pwdVar = $('#password_html').val();
            var whatIsBeingReturned = loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar);
            alert(whatIsBeingReturned);

        });
```

it alerts with 'Undefined'... not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The json that you are returning is in which form. Check with fire bug the json that you are returning is in correct format or not in some json validator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return from ajax.  Unless the ajax is synchronous (don't do it!) You ***cannot*** depend on the code executing in any particular order.  *All* of the functionality that requires a response from ajax has to be in the ajax callback.

```
function loginFunc(userNameOrEmail, passWord){
    ...
    return $.getJSON("http://mysite.com/pullData/login.php?callback=?",
}

$("#loginBtnHtml").on('click', function () {
   //snip
   loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar).done(function (whatIsBeingReturned) {
      console.log(whatIsBeingReturned);
   });
});
```

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution that taught me about `$.when()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Cory - There's no need for `when`. Just call it directly on the jqHXR object returned: `loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar).done(function(){})`.

Comment: Ohhhh! I usually use a different way of AJAX, but this is cross domain so I use this way, had no clue it wasn't async. Thanks so much! It was driving me crazy. It won't allow me to accept the answer for 8 minutes.

Comment: @JosephSilber quite true, but some people seem to be adamant about keeping the callback separate for some reason, so I was solving that problem preemptively

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I don't understand what you said there. Mind explaining that in laymen's terms?

Comment: @JosephSilber so what you're saying is, I can do something like loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar).done(function(returnedData){if(returnedData[0]){//this is true}})?

Comment: @user1053263 - Yes. `when` is only needed when you have to wait for *multiple* requests to finish.

Comment: @JosephSilber What I have is for all intents and purposes identical to `$.getJSON(...).done()`.  I just updated the code so that the actual callback is done in a different spot.  For example, it may make more sense to someone to have the logging done in the `click` event, but if I define the `.done` callback in `loginFunc` it won't be there.  It's just an organizational thing.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - True, but that wasn't my point. Re-read my comment. You can call `.done()` on the object returned from `loginFunc`. No need for `when`.

Comment: @JosephSilber I understand what you mean now.  Yes, you can call `.done` that way, so that works too (and is slightly more efficient by avoiding the extra method call) but I think `$.when` is clearer.  Your comment about only needing `$.when` for *multiple* requests is also not necessarily correct.  It depends on the availability of the callback with respect to the deferred

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Not sure what you mean by *It depends on the availability of the callback with respect to the deferred*.

Comment: @JosephSilber it's plausible (though not likely) that you create a reference to the deferred *before* the callback you want to attack is defined, e.g. `var dfd = $.Deferred(); function callb() {}; $.when(dfd).done(callb);`  Again, it can also be used for organizational reasons.  `$.when` is more likely to be used for multiple deferreds, I'm just saying it's not *always* the only reason

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Again, no need for `when`. The same functionality applies here: `var dfd = $.Deferred(); function callb() {}; dfd.done(callb);`

Comment: @JosephSilber you're right.  Good point.  Will you upvote me if I remove the reference to `$.when`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Sure will. I do believe that, whenever possible, code should be self documenting. But if that'll make you add unnecessary function calls, it's *definitely* not worth it.

Comment: i'm lost, so it's better to use the latter method?

Comment: @JosephSilber getting off topic, but the jQuery docs are pretty unclear about this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ they use `$.when` as a wrapper for a deferred as a primary example.  The use case I can think of for `$.when` for a single argument: having a non-deferred object fail, is not implemented.

Comment: damn thing still won't work.   return $.getJSON("http://mysite.com/pullData/login.php?callback=?",
     {
    emailOrUserName: emailOrUserNameV,
    passWord: passWordV
     }
is that correct?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - They're trying to explain that even if only one deferred is passed to `when`, it'll always only return a promise (as opposed to the deferred itself). They're also trying to demonstrate that the jqXHR object behaves like a deferred. Still, you're right: the documentation *is* confusing.

Comment: @user1053263 - Since you're making the request to your own site, why are you using JSONP? Is your server even set up to serve JSONP (which is JSON wrapped in a callback)? If not, just lose the `callback=?` part of your URL.

Comment: Using JSONP because of cross domain, two different domains and servers .

Answer (score 3):

The response of the JSON request is asynchronous. The `logicFunc()` returns before the the response callback of the JSON request.

You need to write a callback method to handle the response. Something like:

```
function handleResponse(data){ 

     // do something
}


function loginFunc(userNameOrEmail, passWord){
        var emailOrUserNameV = encodeURIComponent(userNameOrEmail);
        var passWordV = encodeURIComponent(passWord);
        $.getJSON("http://mysite.com/pullData/login.php?callback=?",
              {
                emailOrUserName: emailOrUserNameV,
                passWord: passWordV
              },
              handleResponse

        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a callback function instead. The AJAX happens ansync and the completion function can't return a value to the wrapping function.

```
function loginFunc(userNameOrEmail, passWord, callbackFn){
        var emailOrUserNameV = encodeURIComponent(userNameOrEmail);
        var passWordV = encodeURIComponent(passWord);
        $.getJSON("http://mysite.com/pullData/login.php?callback=?",{
            emailOrUserName: emailOrUserNameV,
            passWord: passWordV
        }, callbackFn);
}

$('#loginBtnHtml').click(function(){
    var emailVar = $('#email_html').val();
    var pwdVar = $('#password_html').val();

    loginFunc(emailVar, pwdVar, function(recievedData){
        alert(recievedData[0]);
    });

});
```